# How can I iterate through a drop-down list and click on each option?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The id keeps on changing for the dropdownlist, below is the code:

```
    <select class="select150" 
    onchange="document.getElementById('id1e_hf_0').value='? 
    wicket:interface=:5:remitReaderSearchForm:orgSelection::
    IOnChangeListener::&amp;
    wicket:pcxt=RemitReaderSearchPage';document.getElementById
   ('id1e').submit();" name="orgSelection" id="id1f">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="7623">MCH - Cardiovascular Surgery</option>
  <option value="7598">MCH - Dept. of Orthopedics</option>
  <option value="7610">MCH - Emergency Physicians</option>
  <option value="7603">MCH - ENT</option>
  <option value="13043178">MCH Telehealth</option>
  <option value="13043153">NCH Genetics</option>
  <option value="13043155">NCH Hospitalist</option>
  <option value="13007836">NCH Neurology</option>
  </select>
```

following is the code:

```
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("select150"))
        options = select.options
        for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
            select.select_by_index(index)
```

Traceback:

```
  select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("select150"))
  File "C:\Users\dm050767\Python27\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 555, in 
  find_element_by_class_name
  return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\dm050767\Python27\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in 
  find_element
  'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\dm050767\Python27\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\dm050767\Python27\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
  check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
 element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class 
 name","selector":"select150"}
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315
```

(730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 
   x86_64)

Comment: select the option using the "text" and click

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: `The id keeps on changing` did you try to construct any dynamic locator?

Comment: nop i didnot construct  a dynamic locator

Comment: use this code for selecting the drop down select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("orgSelection"))

Comment: that didnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select ALL options you need to use `range(0, len(options))` instead of `range(0, len(options) - 1)`.

Note that `range(start, end)` will generate indexes from `start` (including) to `end` (excluding)

Also you can try to use below loop:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

select = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "select150"))))
options = select.options

for option in options:
    select.select_by_visible_text(option.text)
```

Comment: This is the stack trace i am getting:     select = Select(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "select150"))))
  File "C:\Users\dm050767\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Check whether Select located inside `iframe` and whether class name `"select150"` is not dynamic

Comment: it is form within which the dropdown is present

Comment: it is form within which the dropdown is present :                           <form id="id1e" method="post" action=" wicket:interface=:5:remitReaderSearchForm::IFormSubmitListener::&amp;wicket:pcxt=RemitReaderSearchPage"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="id1e_hf_0" id="id1e_hf_0"></div></div><div id="orgstuff"><fieldset class="avForm avWideForm"><label for="id1f"><span class="required">

Comment: yup there is an iframe so i added  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("newBodyFrame")) with ure code. did work. Thanks

Comment: Great. Note that you can simplify the line as `driver.switch_to.frame("newBodyFrame")`